# Generalize the usage of moments in method of moments?

Tags: method-of-moments

In Method of Moments for estimation, if there are $k$ parameters to estimate, we usually consider $i$-th moments, $i=1,...,k$, so that we have k equations for k unknowns.

1. I wonder if it is wise to consider more moments of different orders,
   i.e. $i$-th moments, $i=1,...,n>k$, so that we are to solve a
   over-determined linear system? Why?
2. Also would it be better if we choose moments of other orders,
   instead of $i=1,...,k$?

Comment: Related to your questions, but not exactly answering them, sometimes it is useful to consider the method of moments through functions of the observations. For example, in *exponential families*, the maximum likelihood estimators are method of moments estimators *through* the sufficient statistics. For example, if $T_1(X),\ldots,T_p(X)$ are the sufficient statistics, than the MLEs are found by solving the system of $p$ equations: $n^{-1} \sum_j T_i(X_j) = \mathbb E T_i(X)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do either of these and create an estimator, but I would expect it to be of inferior quality, as higher moments are generally less well estimated.  Also, you could imagine a case where the first and third moments are 0, and so with two parameters you'd *need* to look at the 2nd and 4th moments.

If you have a particular case in mind, try out your ideas and check their quality by simulation.

Comment: Thanks, Karl! I wonder what do you mean by "you could imagine a case where the first and third moments are 0, and so with two parameters you'd need to look at the 2nd and 4th moments"?

Comment: @Tim - suppose you have some family of distributions symmetric around 0 but with two free parameters you wish to estimate.  The symmetry around 0 would make all odd moments strictly 0, and so to use MM you'd need to look at even moments.